# Duplicate value in lists. How can I avoid it?

Tags: vb.net, list, winforms

```
Public Class clsA   
    Public icounter As Integer
    Public dtime As DateTime 
End Class

Dim list_A As New List(Of clsA)

Dim dyus As DateTime = DateTime.Now
oB = New clsA
oB.dtime = dyus
oB.counter = counter2 (comes from COM Port)

Dim b As Integer = oB.counter

Dim t1 As TimeSpan = New TimeSpan(0, 1, 0)

list_A.Add(oB)


If DateTime.Now - (list_A(0).dtime) > t1 Then
    If list_A.Sum(Function(x) x.counter) > 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("TEST")
    End If
End If
```

hello,

`list_A.Add(oB)` has 2 values, dtime (`DateTime`) and icounter (`Integer`).

`list_A` is in timer. So it always increases, But I want to avoid duplicate counters in this list.

How can I do that?

The output is:

```
time 1/7/2019 06:10:16 PM
counter 0

time 1/7/2019 06:10:18 PM
counter 0

time 1/7/2019 06:10:20 PM
counter 1

time 1/7/2019 06:10:20 PM
counter 1
```

I want output:

```
time 1/7/2019 06:10:16 PM
counter 0

time 1/7/2019 06:10:20 PM
counter 1
```

Duplicates with counters shouldnt be added (or deleted).

Comment: This isn't C#. This is VB or VBA.

Comment: well it's same for me sorry about mistake.

Comment: @kegnonegni How is this the same for anyone on this planet?

Comment: @Adriani6 , I'm sure they are meaning `My issue is still the same, despite the language being different`.

Comment: @kegnonegni , Could you please add an example of your current output and an example of what your expected/desired output?

Comment: Well, perhaps if you check if the list contains the element before adding it will get rid of the duplicates. Either by reference or utilizing Equals method.

Comment: no i mean you can read it i guess. If you give me answer in c# i can accept it.

Comment: @Symon i edited the original post

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicates in a collection then use a `HashSet` rather than a `List`. Be sure to read all about the `HashSet(Of T)` class before using it.  Don't just assume that it will work a particular way.

Comment: Since you just need to avoid a new *record* when the value of `icounter` is already   existing, you could use a `Dictionary(Of Integer, Date)` instead of your current `clsA` class. You can then use `[Dictionary].ContainsKey(counter2)` to check whether the current Counter value is already present. You can't add a new value to a Dictionary if the key (the Counter, here) is already there. This will forcibly avoid duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate through all of them like so:

```
'New list
Dim list_B As New List(Of clsA)
For each item in list_A
    If Not list_B.Contains(item) Then
        list_B.Add(item)
    End If
Next
```

If you do this at the end you should have a new list called list_B that contains everything that list a cointained, but without duplication